# Writing a Conditional Format Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, formats

I am trying to write a rule in vba to trigger a Conditional Format, but I have my doubts if I am writing it correctly.

The condition for the format would be, if the cell value of a range is equal to the cell value of the same range on a different sheet:
=M7=Original!M7

This is to applied for all cells in a range (M7:BZ5000) [5000 is a large outer bound number to help conserve memory].

The issue that has me perplexed is how do I tell vba that M7=Original!M7, M8=Original!M8, Z143=Original!Z143, etc.

I feel this is a pretty basic concept but I searched these forums and could not find an answer that I think applies to my issue.

Also, Since I Would want this conditional format to trigger at the press of a button, how would I tell it to deactivate, WITHOUT removing the rest of my conditional formats (I have normal conditional formats applied to the range and want them to remain whenever the button isn't pressed.

1. Sheets("Main").Select
2. Range("M7:BZ5000").Select
3. For Each Cell In Selection
4. **If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbBlack Then**
5. Cell.Clear
6. End If
7. Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the conditional formatting choice of "Use formula to determine which cells to format"

The formula you will need is going to be like this (note the use of $ signs to control how the formula changes.  The $ stops the value after it from changing)

```
=AND($M7=Original!$M7,$G$4="Y")
```

Note $G$4 is a cell you can use to turn on and off the cond. formatting.  When it is "Y" the formatting will work, otehrwise any formatting you have applied will JUST be shown.

If you don't want you formatting to show when conditional formatting is on, then your conditional formatting MUST have formats the remove yours and sets them to the "default" settings.

Comment: OMG. I'm dumb. That is absolutely perfect! Thank you. I was over complicating it in VBA. Thank you so much!

Comment: Up arrow and tick answer please.  We all do it.  Golden rule with excel is do it using excel then with VBA if you have to!

Comment: Okay one more Question, I Wrote some code that will go and delete all the contents that the above conditoinal Format highlights, but it seems to be failing. Not an error, it just wont delete the contents. I did a test and Found out because the cell interior color is actually not Black. Any idea how to change my code to read the color of the conditional format (see line 4 added to the code in my above question)

Comment: Sorry, I ticked the Answer checkmark, still new to the etiquette of this forum

Comment: I don't think you need to use clear at all.  Why would you want to get rid of your formatting?  Use a second, CF rule to set cells to default when they don not meet the CF condition AND CF is turned on.

Comment: I should have explained.  I want the cell values to clear because the contents remaining are going to be pasted into a csv. I've already created that portion of this tool that will import the contents of the tab into a new csv file.  I just needed to design a method to clear only the cell values that have been left unchanged to the new csv.

Comment: So you want to delete cell values in your columns where they do not meet a condition.  Why not have a second set of new columns, each column references on of your old columns.  The new columns have a formula with an IF function that only shows the value in the old column if a condition is met.  The code exports the new columns. Job done.